# What does this field notation mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, noetherian

I am reading a problem and its solution posted online [*here*](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~reichst/423-502S13hw-solutions.pdf) that says:

> **Problem 3**: Give an example of a Noetherian ring R that contains a subring that is not Noetherian.

And then,

> **Solution:** The polynomial ring $R = \mathbb C[x_1, x_2, . . .]$ in infinitely many variables is not Noetherian, because the chain of ideals
>   $$(x_1) \subset (x_1, x_2) \subset (x_1, x_2, x_3) \subset . . .$$
>   does not terminate. On the other hand, this ring is contained in the
>   field $\mathbb C(x_1, x_2, . . .)$, and every field is obviously Noetherian.

My question is simple (but perhaps dumb): I know $\mathbb C[x_1, x_2, . . .]$ means polynomial of infinite indeterminate over complex number $\mathbb C$, but what does $\mathbb C(x_1, x_2, . . .)$ mean in field?

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply view it as quotient field of the polynomial ring, i.e., it is obtained the same way you obtain $\Bbb Q$ from $\Bbb Z$ by "allowing" to divide by anything but the zero element.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other notation beside the above, more widely known? Thanks again.

Comment: @A.Magnus: Other notation for what?

Comment: @A.Magnus No. The above is the only widely known one (if widely known entails known by me). Cf. $\Bbb Q[\pi]$ and $\Bbb Q(\pi)$ as the smalles subring and the smallest subfield of $\Bbb R$ containing (both $\Bbb Q$ and) $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a very standard notation. Let $A \subseteq K$ be an extension of rings, where $K$ is a field (hence $A$ is a domain), and let $x \in K$ be any element. Then
$$A[x]$$
denotes the smallest subring of $K$ containing $A \cup \{ x \}$, while
$$A(x)$$
denotes the smallest subfield of $K$ containing $A \cup \{ x \}$. In the particular case when $A$ is a field, we have that $A(x)$ is the fraction field of $A[x]$.

Similarly, if you have any subset $S \subseteq K$, you denote
$$A[S]$$
as the smallest subring of $K$ containing $A \cup S$, and
$$A(S)$$
denotes the smallest subfield of $K$ containing $A \cup S$.

Following this notation, it is quite clear that $\Bbb{C}(x_1, x_2, \dots )$ denotes the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $\Bbb{C}[x_1, x_2, \dots ]$.

Comment: I think this is confusing. In the context of the OP's question all you needed to say was the last line: $\mathbb{C}(x_1, x_2, \dots)$ is the field of fractions of $\mathbb{C}[x_1, x_2, \dots]$. The rest of your answer doesn't apply to the OP's question, since the $x_i$ are not particular elements of a larger field $K$.

Comment: They are: the larger field is actually the field $\mathbb{C}(x_1, x_2, \dots )$ itself.

Comment: But the OP's entire problem is that they don't know what field this is!